# Accelerated C++problem - functions which call functions

Tags: c++

I am having trouble with an exercise in Accelerated C++.
The main function is as follows:

```
int main()
{
 // students who did and didn't do all their homework
 vector<Student_info> did, didnt;

 // read the student records and partition them
 Student_info student;
 while (read(cin, student)) {
  if (did_all_hw(student))
   did.push_back(student);
  else
   didnt.push_back(student);
 }

 // verify that the analyses will show us something
 if (did.empty()) {
  cout << "No student did all the homework!" << endl;
  return 1;
 }
 if (didnt.empty()) {
  cout << "Every student did all the homework!" << endl;
  return 1;
 }


 // do the analyses
 write_analysis(cout, "median", median_analysis, did, didnt);
 write_analysis(cout, "average", average_analysis, did, didnt);
 write_analysis(cout, "median of homework turned in",
                optimistic_median_analysis, did, didnt);

 return 0;
}
```

The function write_analysis takes 5 parameters, the third of which, analysis, is a function.

Write analysis is as follows:

```
void write_analysis(ostream& out, const string& name,
                    double analysis(const vector<Student_info>&),
                    const vector<Student_info>& did,
                    const vector<Student_info>& didnt)
{
 out << name << ": median(did) = " << analysis(did) <<
                ", median(didnt) = " << analysis(didnt) << endl;
}
```

The question asks the reader to write an analysis function to call optimistic_median, where optimistic median is:

```
double optimistic_median(const Student_info& s)
{
 vector<double> nonzero;
 remove_copy(s.homework.begin(), s.homework.end(),
             back_inserter(nonzero), 0);

 if (nonzero.empty())
  return grade(s.midterm, s.final, 0);
 else
  return grade(s.midterm, s.final, median(nonzero));
}
```

Then, presumably, one can get the write_analysis function to work, which it does not seem to do for me.
I have tried

```
double analysis(const Student_info& s)
{ 

 optimistic_median(s);

}
```

But it doesn’t work. 
Anyone able to help?

Comment: You can format your code correctly by indenting it four spaces.

Comment: In the future, please format your code snippets by highlighting them and pressing Ctrl+K, or hitting the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  What does it do, vs what you expect?

Comment: Hi, @SteveH, the accepted answer is downright wrong. Mine is correct. Please reconsider. cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to use the appropriate name for the analysis function. That would be `optimistic_median_analysis`. Next, you have to take in a reference to the vector, iterate over each item and apply the `optimistic_median` function to it.

```
double optimistic_median_analysis(const vector<Student_info> &v)
{
    return std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0, optimistic_median) / v.size();
}
```

This would give you the average for each student, but it is unclear from your question exactly what output is required.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to your `analysis` function is a single student, not a `vector` of them which is what you're passing in.

I think your analysis function should accept a `vector` of students, iterate over each one, and call `optimistic_median` for each student.

Answer (score 0):

```
void write_analysis(ostream& out, const string& name,
                    double analysis(const vector<Student_info>&),
                    const vector<Student_info>& did,
                    const vector<Student_info>& didnt)
```

One problem is that here you're trying to pass a function as a parameter to a function. You can't do that -- you can pass a pointer to a function, but not an actual function.

Answer (score -1):

I'm doing the exercises and this is the right answer. As noted on page 110 of the book, we have to "report the median grade of each group", ie. the group of optimistic medians.

```
double optimistic_median_analysis (const vector<Student_info> &s) {
    vector<double> optgrades;
    transform(s.begin(), s.end(), back_inserter(optgrades), optimistic_median);
    return median(optgrades);
}
```